# Mapping of TDMA frame on to E1 frame

Tags: wireless, communication, gsm

In a GSM network TDMA frame is used to transmit information between Base station and Mobile staton and E1 frame is used as the media to carry information to and in the Backhaul. How is th TDMA frame of 8 time slots mapped onto the E1 frame of 32time slots?

Answer (score 1):

It isn't. [As we discussed before](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/55472/11683), the transfer between the over-the-air protocol and the wire protocol happens at a higher level (the packet level).

A direct mapping from air timeslots to wire timeslots would be very inefficient for the wire, since air timeslots are mostly empty.

Comment: I am getting confused.


TDMA frame of 8 TS is used in Air interface on which the traffic is carried to BTS. The BTS to BTS and to BSC and to MSC is carried on E1. Then I think it would be a wrong question to ask how many calls an E1 handle, cos its just carrying the information from BTS to MSC. Then I see your explanation of 480 calls per E1 frame and get confused.